# JSON variable block

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I am having json template for elasticsearch query:

```
var getTemplate = function (agg, filter_term) {
var template = {
    "size": 0,
    track_total_hits: true,
    query: {
        bool: {
            must: [
                {
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": filter_term
                    }
                },
 aggs: {
          "nested" : { "value_count" : { "field" : agg } },
        agg: {
            terms: {
                field: agg,
                size: 10,
                order: {
                    "_count": "desc"
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
return template;
```

Sometimes, I want to skip the block with query_string so I want to pass in in the function call. So instead of this:

```
 const callTerminated = agg_filter.getTemplate( 'bbbbb', 'aaa');
```

Do that:

```
  const callTerminated = agg_filter.getTemplate( 'bbbbb', {"query_string": {"query": aaa }});
```

Or:

```
  const callTerminated = agg_filter.getTemplate( 'bbbbb', "");
```

But how to change the template query? It wants comma after variable but when I skip query_string, I don't need comma.

New json template:

```
   var getTemplate = function (agg, filter_term) {
var template = {
    "size": 0,
    track_total_hits: true,
    query: {
        bool: {
            must: [
                filter_term //here it wants comma
 aggs: {
          "nested" : { "value_count" : { "field" : agg } },
        agg: {
            terms: {
                field: agg,
                size: 10,
                order: {
                    "_count": "desc"
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
return template;
```

So how to do it?

Comment: Do you want to do fulltext-searches or exact searches?

Comment: I think it doesn't matter. I just need to have variable where I pass query_string or nothing into template.

Comment: When you pass an empty string: Why don't you check for that empty string and do an if-else block and/or create a temporary variable?

Comment: What do you mean by temporary variable? How will you insert it into template?